# Cannot find .config file for a dynamically loaded 3rd party assembly used by ASP.NET Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, config

C#, VS2010, .Net 4.0, ASP.NET service under IIS or IIS Express.

I'm using a 3rd party assembly within my service. This 3rd party assembly has a .config file and is loaded dynamically as such:

Service -> MyAssembly1 -> Dynamically Load MyAssembly2 using Assembly.Load() -> 3rd Party Assembly with .config

I'm normally a C++ developer so this ASP.NET stuff is rather new to me.
I understand that with an ASP.NET application the assemblies it uses are "shadow-copied" to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder.
Unfortunately when this 3rd party assembly is "shadow-copied" its .config file is not. So when it comes time to use this assembly it's failing because it cannot open its .config file.

From within my assembly I'm able to get the CodeBase for that assembly and load the .config file myself, but that doesn't help me since this 3rd party assembly needs to open the file itself.

If I manually copy the .config file to the shadow-copy location it works great.

Also, this 3rd party called the config file "assemblyname.config" instead of "assemblyname.dll.config".

The error I get is:

```
Unable to load configuration file: "\assemblyname.config".
```

When this 3rd party assembly is used in a non ASP.NET app (ie a normal Windows app) it works great since it doesn't do the shadow-copy stuff. Just uses the assembly and .config file directly from the exe location.

Any ideas? I've been unable to find a solution though I'd think this would be a rather common issue.

Comment: What is it trying to get from the config file?

Comment: @Jeroen, it's a 3rd party assembly which we have no control over what it's doing. First time we try to use it we get an error that the configuration file couldn't be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing when loading assemblies is to see the path where the assembly is placed on disk and the page directory from which you are trying to load the assembly. So if you are adding the path for loading the assembly that does not mean that from the same path it will load the config file. Please try to put them both in the root folder of the app and see if the issue remains.

Comment: When the application is built, everything is in the same folder. NOTE: no deployment, this is all via debugging, in case that makes a difference. During execution, the assemblies are shadow-copied to their own folder (each assembly in it's own folder). This is a process that I assume we have no control over. We dynamically load our own second assembly via name, not path, ie Assembly.Load("Assembly2"), which uses this 3rd party assembly, but that assembly is loaded (via project reference) at the same time our second assembly is loaded, we don't actually dynamically load that.